# MySQL union limit being slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT result.globalId AS id, result.date, p1.playerName AS player, p2.playerName AS target, w.weaponIngameName AS weapon, result.headshot, s.serverName AS server, result.origin
FROM ((SELECT globalId, date, serverId, playerId, targetId, weaponId, headshot, 'playerkills' AS origin 
FROM playerkills
ORDER BY date DESC)
UNION
(SELECT globalId, date, serverId, playerId, null, null, null, 'playersuicides' AS origin 
FROM playersuicides
ORDER BY date DESC) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 300) result
LEFT JOIN players p1 ON result.playerId = p1.playerId
LEFT JOIN players p2 ON result.targetId = p2.playerId
LEFT JOIN weapons w ON result.weaponId = w.weaponId
LEFT JOIN servers s ON result.serverId = s.serverId
ORDER BY result.date DESC, result.globalId DESC;
```

And it is taking long to calculate, it's unneccesary and I've found the cause: The `UNION` puts the tables in memory in order to do the `LIMIT`, if I put the `LIMIT` inside the individuals queries then everything is fine.

**How do I go about fixing it such that this (kind of) query executes as fast as possible?** Obviously I cannot `LIMIT` the two `SELECT`-queries inside the `UNION` as I do not know how many of the 300 results are going to come from either one.

When profiled it shows that pretty much 99% of the execution time is due to this sequence in the middle of the query: Sending data + Converting HEAP to MySIAM + Sending data.

**EDIT: Additional information**

The original query as shown at the start of my post takes averagely 4~6 seconds to execute.

When I put the `LIMIT` inside the original queries, respectively by 295 on `playerkills` and 5 on `playersuicides` the query executes in 50 milliseconds.

Comment: You should also post the table structure off the tables you use and an explain off this query.. the answer are based on guessing right now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit 300 rows from each of these tables, union them and limit final 300 rows. In this way you are sure not to miss out on rows.

Comment: That's a fair enough decision. Though I consider it more 'hackish', maybe someone else can come up with a different answer.

Comment: A bit hackish indeed, but if it increases speed from 5 seconds to 50ms I would settle for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. `UNION` filters duplicates so takes more time. It isn't necessary, since this query seems never to return any dupicaties.

I don't know how much faster this will make the query, but maybe you can combine this with other answers.

Comment: It went from 4.8s to 0.8s. Appreciate your answer a lot aswell!

Comment: That's a great performance increase, but 0.8 is pretty long as well. I hope you'll find additional ways to make it faster.

Comment: Well those times were without the suggestion from @user3020494 - with his suggestion both queries (with and without your suggestion) run in 50ms.